# DC boosting converter design

Tags: pcb, layout

I use the lt3471 to generate +/-9v for my portable headphone amp so i'm trying to make the voltage output as clean as possble and less affect to analog circuit. One of my concern in layouting this is how does the switching current go?

[image: Current loop when switch open]

[image: Current loop when switch close]

The converter operating at 1.2Mhz so i think the current switch at very high frequency, so the return current is right under the trace where current come in.
At the possitive converter (lower half), the first picture is what i thought when switch open: current flow from input capacitor (yellow trace), to inductor, charge Cout and then return from the gnd via of output capacitor (orange trace), go right under the yellow trace and back to input capacitor ground.
The second picture is when switch close: current flow from Cin to inductor then go back to the Cin's gnd through Gnd pin of the converter.
Am i correct? I can only post 2 picture so i can't post the schematic but it's exactly what's in the datasheet.

Comment: There's only one picture there, not clear what you're doing, we need a schematic as well as a layout. However, it looks like you are concerned about some of the right things.

Comment: I have just updated the picture to make it more clear, thanks!

Comment: What are you exactly concerned about? Your layout doesn't look that bad. I would rotate C8 90degs and also increase the switching node (coil - diode - chip) size, e.g. rotating C61 too. Anyway, add a schematic please.

Comment: @VladimirCravero yeah, i don't think it's bad but i want to improve it as much as i could. Here is the schematic:http://imgur.com/a/iKUar. What i am asking is does the current flow as i draw or does it go directly from load back to input capacitor? because i read this article http://www.analog.com/media/en/analog-dialogue/volume-41/number-2/articles/reducing-ground-bounce-in-dc-to-dc-converters.pdf and i want to reduce the change in current loop so i need to know how does it go.

Comment: Yes it does flow as you depicted, provided there is a ground pour on bottom layer. Rotating the caps you can reduce the HF loop, and please do increase the switching node size.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the high speed current loop in the boost converter:

GND - input cap - inductor - and then:

FET ON: FET - GND
FET OFF: diode - output cap - GND

You want the last two GNDs to be tied together at the same point. This means sticking the GND pin of the output cap next to the GND pin of your IC. This will avoid transporting high frequency, high di/dt currents through the ground plane.

Current flowing through the inductor and input cap is smoothed, so it is less of a problem.

Do the same for the other converter. It is only a simple tweak to your layout. Always think about loops!

Now, since boost converters generate lots of noise on the output, due to the discontinuous output current, you might want to add a simple LC filter, with a ferrite bead and caps. These are cheap and work wonders on HF noise. Murata provides spice models for their ferrite beads, so you can check transfer function in simulation.